# passing names into an array and sorting them

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

what im tryng to do is enter a first and last name into a textarea, once the "enter name" button is hit the names will go into an array, where they are sorted, then put back into a string and displayed in the "output" box. everytime a name is entered it will be added into the same array and sorted.

I was able to get the names into an array, and displayed in the output box, but i cant get it to add names to the list, or sort them alphabeticly. it just replaces them. I thought i could use push to add the names, but it doesnt seem to work. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

here is what i have so far:

```
<body>
<p>
<label for="name">Enter First and Last Name: </label>
<input id="name" name="name" />
<input type="button" id="addNameBtn" value="Enter Name" />
<input type="button" id="clearBtn" value="Clear Output" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="output">Output:</label><br />
<textarea cols="20" rows="15" id="output" ></textarea>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">grabText();</script> 
</body>
</html>


`function grabText(){
  var arr = [];
  var arr2 =[];
  var len = arr.length;
  for (var i = 0; i<len; i++);
    {
      var txt = document.getElementById('name').value;
      var textArea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
      if (txt !=="")
      {
        arr.push(txt);
      }
    }
      arr2.push(arr);
      arr2.sort();
  var arrStr = arr2.join();
      textArea[0].value = arrStr;
      document.getElementById('name').value = '';
}
var btn = document.getElementById('addNameBtn');
btn.onclick = grabText;`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Playground](http://jsbin.com/sogim/1/edit)

```
var textArea = document.getElementById('output');
var name     = document.getElementById('name');
var btn      = document.getElementById('addNameBtn');
var arr = [];
// Why whould you need arr2? to store the original?

function grabText(){
  var txt = name.value;
  if (txt !==""){
     arr.push(txt);
  }
  arr.sort();
  var arrStr = arr.join(); 
  textArea.value = arrStr;
  name.value = '';
}

btn.onclick = grabText;
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. If i had a higher reputation i would up vote you.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. The for statement `for (var i = 0; i<len; i++);` - notice the very last character - a semi-colon.  This for statement does very little - it evaluates and increments i, not the statements which follow.
2. `var len = arr.length;` syntax is correct, but the problem is arr is declared immediately before it and has a length of zero.
3. `var arr2` stores the contents between invocations, but it has function scope and needs to be moved outside of the grabText function.